# Can the home team win an extra-inning baseball game by more than 1 run?

Tags: baseball

In baseball, I'm wondering how home teams are awarded winning runs. If the visiting team in, say, Inning 10, plates 5 runs, then the home team has the bottom of that inning to match or exceed this number.

But what if this scenario occurs: game is tied in the 10th with the home team up to bat. 1 runner is on base, and the batter launches a home run over the fence. The game is clearly over via a "walk-off" at this point, but since the home team doesn't "need" 2 runs to win (remember, it's tied), are they only awarded the 1 run from the on-base runner? Or are they given a 2-run win? If it's the former, is the batter then only awarded a single RBI for his stats, thus "robbing" him of the extra RBI (in this case, himself)?

TL;DR: can the home team in an extra-inning baseball game *ever* win said game by more than 1 run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Baseball Almanac](http://www.baseball-almanac.com/rulechng.shtml) prior to 1920 this was not possible.  In fact, if a runner was on base, the batter would not be given credit for a home run.

However, this is now explicitly allowed in the [rules](https://content.mlb.com/documents/2/2/4/305750224/2019_Official_Baseball_Rules_FINAL_.pdf).

While 7.01(g)(3) states that

> ... the game ends immediately when the winning run is scored.

it also lists the exception for home runs:

> EXCEPTION: If the last batter in a game hits a home run out of the
>   playing field, the batter-runner and all runners on base are permitted
>   to score...

So with runners on base, a home team can win in the bottom of the ninth or later by up to 4 runs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the home team certainly can win by more than one run.

For an example, see [Royals vs Tigers on 2019-05-05](http://www.espn.com/mlb/boxscore?gameId=401075232): the score was tied at 2 after nine innings, the Royals didn't score in the top of the tenth, but then in the bottom of the 9th [Brandon Dixon](http://www.espn.com/mlb/player/_/id/33911) hit a three-run home to win the game 5-2.